# FROM keyword not found where expected When in a INSERT Statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hello currently doing a school work, I have to create a MANAGE BOOKS package, I am getting an ODD error where it tells me that a FROM keyword is not found where it is expected however where this ERROR is there is no SELECT or Revoke statement I am confused as where that FROM statement would take place if someone could enlighten me on this It would be really appreciated!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MANAGE_BOOKS
AS
    PROCEDURE ADD_BOOK(i_Book_ID IN NUMBER, i_Title IN VARCHAR2, i_Category IN VARCHAR2, i_Cost IN NUMBER);

    PROCEDURE REMOVE_BOOK(i_Book_ID IN NUMBER);

    PROCEDURE LIST_ALL_BOOKS(i_Status IN VARCHAR2);

    PROCEDURE UPDATE_BOOK_Status(i_Book_ID IN NUMBER, i_Status IN VARCHAR2);

    FUNCTION GET_BOOK_STATUS(i_Book_ID IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2;

END MANAGE_BOOKS;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MANAGE_BOOKS
AS
    PROCEDURE ADD_BOOK(i_Book_ID IN NUMBER, i_Title IN VARCHAR2, i_Category IN VARCHAR2, i_Cost IN NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO BOOK
        (BOOK_ID, TITLE, CATEGORY, STATUS, LOST_COST)
        VALUES
        (i_Book_ID, i_Title, i_Category, "AVAILABLE", i_Cost);
    END ADD_BOOK;

    PROCEDURE REMOVE_BOOK(i_Book_ID IN NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Book WHERE BOOK_ID = i_Book_ID;
    END REMOVE_BOOK;

    PROCEDURE LIST_ALL_BOOKS(i_Status IN VARCHAR2(20))
    IS
        c_bookid Book.BOOK_ID%TYPE;
        c_booktitle Book.TITLE%TYPE;
        CURSOR c_books IS
            SELECT BOOK_ID, TITLE FROM Book WHERE STATUS = i_Status;
    BEGIN
        OPEN c_books;
        LOOP
            FETCH c_books into c_bookid, c_booktitle;
                EXIT WHEN c_books%notfound;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c_bookid || ' ' || c_booktitle);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c_books;
    END LIST_ALL_BOOKS;

    PROCEDURE UPDATE_BOOK_Status(i_Book_ID IN NUMBER, i_Status IN VARCHAR2)
    IS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Book SET STATUS = i_Status WHERE Book_ID = i_Book_ID;
    END UPDATE_BOOK_Status;

    FUNCTION GET_BOOK_STATUS(i_Book_ID IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
    v_status BOOK.STATUS%TYPE;
    BEGIN
        SELECT Status INTO v_status FROM Book WHERE Book_ID = i_Book_ID;
        RETURN v_status;
    END;

END MANAGE_BOOKS;
/
```

```
23/13    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
23/35    PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Comment: ˋSELECT BOOK_ID, TITLE WHERE STATUS = i_Status;ˋ is indeed missing a ˋFROMˋ

Comment: Thanks for that, however I still have the same initial error I was getting at the beginning The error I am getting is on line 23 which is "VALUES"

Comment: The FROM needs to be _before_ the WHERE `select .. from .. where ...`

Comment: strings in Oracle are delimited by single quotes (`'`) not double-quotes. you want `..., 'AVAILABLE', ...` not `..., "AVAILABLE", ...` in your insert statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- cursor `c_books` has `FROM` at the wrong place
- variable `v_status` is `varchar2`, but - size is missing. You'd rather declare it as `v_status book.status%type;`

Comment: Done this, now I am getting another error I am getting 18/50    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ) , @ % default character
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.

Comment: Which line is #18, and what's at position #50?

Comment: Line 18 is the declaration of my procedure I was missing a "IN" inbetween i_Cost and Number thought this might have been the error however the error remains

Comment: Edit the original question you posted and copy/paste your **current** code. It is difficult to debug code you can't see.

Comment: Updated just now

Comment: Use single quotes to enclose strings, not double quotes, That's `"AVAILABLE"` which is wrong.